# output has multiple id's and i need 1 id

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

i got a json fetcher and its working fine. but when i need an ID. it sends out all the id's that are in the json.

i need only the latest one, could that be possible?

Its the first time that i am working on json so i am currently noob in it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("https://api.omny.fm/orgs/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/",function(data) {
      $('#table').html(data.Clips.map(studentData => `${studentData.Id}`).join(''));
    });
});
```

added [:1] and [0] but that didn't work sadly

Comment: `$('#table').html(data.Clips[0].Id)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `[0]` accessor

also I added `?pageSize=1` to the url so it just download one record

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("https://api.omny.fm/orgs/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/?pageSize=1",function(data) {
     
      $('#table').html(data.Clips[0].Id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: The script here above selects the latest id and i need the upperst id.

Comment: @AndorBird I edited my answer but you asked for the latest in your question

Comment: @R4ncid I guess we need to know your definition of "latest" and "upperst" (whatever that means). Because "latest" = last item in the array. So, the last item can be taken out the array with `myarray.pull()` or by using `myarray[myarra.length-1]` if you don't need change the array.